# Why can the same user make a directory on the command line but not via the webserver?

Tags: apache

I am running Apache on CentOS and in my /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf file the User and Group are both `my-username`

```
$ cat /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf|grep '^User'
User my-username
$ cat /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf|grep '^Group'
Group my-username
```

When I run as `my-username` on the command line I can create a directory, but not via a call to the webserver.

```
$ cat test.php
<?php 
mkdir(dirname(__FILE__) . '/made-by-the-webserver', 0755);
$err = error_get_last();
$user = exec('whoami');
echo 'Whie attempting to create a directory, we got ' . $err['message'] . ' running as ' . $user;

$ curl mysite.local/test.php
Whie attempting to create a directory, we got mkdir(): Permission denied running as my-username

$ whoami
my-username

$ mkdir made-on-the-command-line

$ ls -lah|grep made

drwxrwxr-x.  2 my-username my-username 4.0K Dec 16 14:51 made-on-the-command-line

$ php test.php

Whie attempting to create a directory, we got   running as my-username

$ ls -lah|grep made

drwxr-xr-x.  2 my-username my-username 4.0K Dec 16 14:52 made-by-the-webserver
drwxrwxr-x.  2 my-username my-username 4.0K Dec 16 14:51 made-on-the-command-line
```

I would expect that, because Apache is running the user `my-username`, and `my-username` is allowed to create directories on the command line, it would also be allowed to create directories during a call to Apache.

Any help in debugging this greatly appreciated, thanks!

Albert.

Comment: This might be related to http://selinuxproject.org/page/Main_Page being installed on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Almost certainly due to SELinux. Perhaps httpd_sys_script_rw_t property on the parent directory is needed?